# Grails Version: 3.3.2 create-app command not found

Tags: grails

I am trying to follow the Grails document to create Hello world application.  looks like create-app command not available in Grails 3.3.2 version any more.

http://docs.grails.org/snapshot/guide/gettingStarted.html#creatingAnApplication

```
 grails create-app helloworld
| Error Command not found create-app
Did you mean: create-script or create-taglib or create-unit-test?
```

Do we need to follow the profile option to create web application?

Thanks
SR